# Center input field in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web

This code show the input to the left of div

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7" style="min-width: 270px;">
<input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo$data["address"]; ?>">
</div>
```

I intent with center and align div and show same. Sorry for the english. Thanks very much. Regards

Comment: yes, but not center...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, then the following should center the input field:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7" style="min-width: 270px;">
<input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo$data["address"]; ?>" style="margin: auto;">
</div>
```

By default though, Bootstrap's `.form-control` fields are set to 100% width so you won't notice any difference. You could add `width: 50%` for example and then you would see it appear in the center.

**Updated answer:**

It looks like you need to center the container div rather than the input field. You can use [col-md-offset-*](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) to do that:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-md-offset-2" style="min-width: 270px;">
<input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo$data["address"]; ?>">
</div>
```

As Bootstrap's grid consists of 12 columns, this won't center it exactly while you are using col-md-7. You would need to use col-md-8 and col-md-offset-2 to make it exactly center.

Comment: Thanks but the two options not set, the 50% reduce the input but it continue in the left.

Comment: Here's a working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpgxPL Could you create your own Codepen with your complete code?

Comment: your the best! thanks for the explanation! Best Regards